# Problem creating datatable via code and binding to a datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I am trying to bind my data table inventorytable to the datagrid viewer.the problem in the code is when it compiles,it says the column"make" does not belong to the table but I make the column in the code as follows:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Car> listCars = new List<Car>();
        DataTable inventorytable=new DataTable();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listCars.Add(new Car("Chucky", "BMW", "Green"));
            listCars.Add(new Car("Tiny", "Yugo", "White"));
            listCars.Add(new Car("Ami", "Jeep", "Tan"));
            listCars.Add(new Car("Pain Inducer", "Caravan", "Pink"));
            listCars.Add(new Car("Fred", "BMW", "Pea Soup Green"));
            listCars.Add(new Car("Sidd", "BMW", "Black"));
            listCars.Add(new Car("Mel", "Firebird", "Red"));
            listCars.Add(new Car("Sarah", "Colt", "Black"));
            createdatatable();
        }
        void createdatatable()//create data table schema
        {
            DataColumn carmake = new DataColumn("make", typeof(string));
            DataColumn carcolor = new DataColumn("color", typeof(string));
            DataColumn carpetname = new DataColumn("petname", typeof(string));
            foreach (Car c in listCars)
            {
                DataRow dr = inventorytable.NewRow();
                **dr["make"] = c.carMake;**//column 'make' does not belong to the table.
                dr["color"] = c.carColor;
                dr["petname"] = c.carPetName;
                inventorytable.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = inventorytable;//binds data table to the grid view

        }

    }
}
```

I have also added a class to this form named as car whose code is as follows:

```
class Car
    {
        public string carPetName { get; set; }
        public string carMake { get; set; }
        public string carColor { get; set; }
        public Car(string petname, string make, string color)
        {
            carPetName = petname;
            carMake = make;
            carColor = color;
        }
```

please help!!!!!!!!  P.S. (I wrote the statement as

```
DataTable inventorytable=new DataTable();
```

because when I wrote it as `DataTable inventorytable`, it was giving an exception as 
"object refence not set to an instance of an object ".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
DataColumn carmake = new DataColumn("make", typeof(string)); 
DataColumn carcolor = new DataColumn("color", typeof(string)); 
DataColumn carpetname = new DataColumn("petname", typeof(string));

// Your missing this part:
inventorytable.Columns.Add(carmake);
inventorytable.Columns.Add(carcolor);
inventorytable.Columns.Add(carpetname);
```

You forgot to add the columns to the table so when you create the row, it has no columns in it and your code fails the column name lookup.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have missed adding the columns that you have created dynamically to your datatable.
In the `createdatatable` function, you need a

```
inventorytable.Columns.Add(carmake)
```

after  the line

```
`DataColumn carmake = new DataColumn("make", typeof(string));`
```

Comment: @In Sane yup i did the mistake of not adding the column ... now i have rectified the mistake....anyways thanx for pointing out the mistake!!!

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the columns, but, not adding them to the table. So, you need to add the code mentioned by "Kelsey".

=========================================================
Always remember to mark an answer if you find it correct.
This will encourage the community to answer your questions.